# Flask-AppBuilder how to set primary key on create?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-appbuilder

My users should be able to create new rows for my table, but when I use the plus-button in Flask-AppBuilder, the primary key is not shown and the generated SQL INSERT statement is missing the primary key, which obviously fails.

How can I get Flask-AppBuilder to show the primary key for new rows?

### Example

#### models.py

```
class Catalogue(Model):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    id = Column(String(200), primary_key=True)
    label =  Column(String(200), nullable=False)
    type =  Column(Enum("UserGroup","ApplicationSystem","Feature","EnterpriseFunction","OrganizationalUnit"), nullable=False)
```

#### views.py

```
class CatalogueView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Catalogue)
    label_columns = {'label':'Name', }
    list_columns = ['id', 'label', 'type']
    related_views = [ClassifiedView]
```

Now when I run the application, I can see the "id" field in the view `http://127.0.0.1:5000/catalogueview/list/`.

However when I enter the detail view at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/catalogueview/show/myexamplecatalogue`, then the primary key field "id" is hidden and the same happens when creating a new entry using `http://127.0.0.1:5000/catalogueview/add`, which then fails as stated above.

How can I stop Flask-AppBuilder from hiding my primary key and successfully create new entries?

Comment: Maybe try using `add_columns` to override what is shown in the add form: https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickhowto.html#flask_appbuilder.baseviews.BaseCRUDView.add_columns

Comment: @IljaEverilä: But why is something as important as a primary key missing in the first place? It is impossible to create an entry without it.

Comment: Most of the time people use autogenerated surrogate keys, so it is entirely up to the DB to generate one, and it could be even harmful to let people manually define it.

Comment: Übrigens habe ich keine Erfahrung mit Flask-Appbuilder.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks for the explanation, I'm used to the Semantic Web, where the primary key is a URI that is manually defined, I will look into the add_columns method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @IljaEverilä, this can be added using the "edit_columns" attribute:

```
class CatalogueView(ModelView):
  datamodel = SQLAInterface(Catalogue)
  label_columns = {'label':'Name', }
  list_columns = ['id', 'label', 'type']
  related_views = [ClassifiedView]
  edit_columns = ['id', 'label', 'type']
```